# Update Access Database from DataGridView Changes

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, oledb, oledbdataadapter

I need to update my Access database after I make changes to my `DataGridView` called `DataGridView_Manage_Calculations` and then click a `Button` called `Button_Update`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim dtManage As New DataTable
Dim ManageAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim Bsource As New BindingSource

Public Sub Show_Panel_Manage_Calculations()
    Panel_Manage_Calculations.Show()

    ManageAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select Calculation, [Interval], Formula From " & tblName & "", con)
    dtManage.Clear()
    ManageAdapter.Fill(dtManage)
    Bsource.DataSource = dtManage
    DataGridView_Manage_Calculations.DataSource = Bsource

End Sub

Private Sub Button_Update_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_Update.Click
    Dim ObjComander As New OleDbCommandBuilder(ManageAdapter)
    ManageAdapter.Update(dtManage)
End Sub
```

I get this error: `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.`

What am I doing wrong?

**Additional Information**

```
Public Sub createTable_Criteria()
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("CREATE TABLE " & tblName & "(" & "Calculation Text(10) NOT NULL," & "[Interval] Text NOT NULL," & "Formula Text," & "Tier_Juncture_1 Integer," & "Tier_Juncture_2 Integer," & "Tier_Juncture_3 Integer," & "Weight Integer, CONSTRAINT pk_Calculation PRIMARY KEY (Calculation, [Interval]));", con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Sub
```

Comment: You could try to put a breakpoint on the UPDATE command and try to look at the InsertCommand.CommandText property inside the adapter. Could you show that text?

Comment: @Steve I'm not quite sure what it is that you're suggesting I look at.

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets5p6.html

Comment: @Steve I understand debugging and breakpoints.  I just don't understand what exactly you're suggesting I look at.

Comment: The OleDbDataAdapter contains a property called InsertCommand that is prepared by the OleDbCommandBuilder with the command that is used by the Update statement. The InsertCommand contains the property CommandText and according to your error message this text is wrong. Looking at it could be fundamental to understand what is causing the error.

Comment: @Steve I got this error `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at this line of code `Debug.WriteLine(ManageAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText)`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your info on the error message it seems that your SELECT query doesn't return a Primary Key for the table in the select statement. In this case the OleDbCommandBuilder doesn't build the INSERT command required.

You have two options:

- Return the primary key for the table selected
- Create your own INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands for the Adapter

I don't know the structure of your table (given the dinamically constructed select) but the best approach is to return the primary key in the select statement

Comment: That sounds good.  How exactly do I return the primary key in the select statement?

Comment: Check your table in the database and add that field to the select statement. For example if your table has an autonumber field probably is also a primarykey. (The small key in the design of the table). Add that field to the select.

Comment: I see what you mean.  My primary key consists of the fields `Calculation` and `[Interval]`.  These are already returned in my select statement.  I've added the code I use to create the table to my original post.

Comment: I will try to move the initialization of the OleDbCommandBuilder directly after the creation of the OleDbAdapter inside the `Show_Panel_Manage_Calculations` method

Comment: Should be something that is not visible from your code above. I wish to help, but I have no more ideas. Do you mind to share the project? If yes zip and post project and database on a sharing host like gdrive, skydrive, dropbox and post the link here.